Appropriateness of adding a tag to a question when the issue is not specifically asked about, but comes up in an answer
Apologies for the long title.
I have been adding the regression-to-the-mean tag to old questions where it is asked about, but I notice several questions that don't mention it specifically, but the answer to the question is directly related to RTM. In these cases, is it appropriate to add the tag ? So far I have only added the tag where it is mentioned as part of the question.
Here is an example:
If Galton did not use least squares then how was he drawing his regression slopes?

This has been asked & answered before, and the consensus was that tag should be based also an answers  https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1525/should-tags-refer-to-the-answer-as-well-as-the-question
